# Why does Safari blur images under an overlapping canvas?

Tags: canvas, safari

This codepen contains an image and a transparent HTML canvas on top of it. When the canvas appears, the image is blurred. How can I avoid this blurring?

[image: Without canvas, image is crisp]

[image: With canvas, image is pixellated]

```js
function hideCanvas() {
  document.querySelector("#mycanvas").style.display = "none";
}

function showCanvas() {
  document.querySelector("#mycanvas").style.display = "inline-block";
}

// draw something on the canvas to trigger the bug
let ctx = document.querySelector("#mycanvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
button {
  z-index: 1;
}

.transformed {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-0.3px) translateY(0.88px) scale(2.0);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

#mycanvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hideCanvas()">Hide  canvas</button>
<button onclick="showCanvas()">Show  canvas</button>


<div class="transformed">
  <div style="background-size:contain;background-image:url('https://zwibbler.com/clipart/image/105446-2000px.png');width:1000px;height:1000px;background-size:contain"></div>

  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500" style="display:none"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to raise an issue at https://bugs.webkit.org.
Note that this seems to only affect non-retina devices. On High-res monitors I couldn't see any change.

My guess would be that they change which renderer they use when the canvas is present and the transform is made over a snapshot of the rendered `<div>`, instead of re-rendering it transformed.

Anyway, to workaround that issue, you can apply the transform separately on the `<div>` and on the `<canvas>`, this will avoid this bug.

```js
let ctx = document.querySelector("#mycanvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
button {
  z-index: 1;
}
.transformed {
  position: relative;
}

/* When hovering the body, remove the transform fromt the parent
   and apply it to the div and the canvas instead. */
body:not(:hover) .transformed,
body:hover .transformed > * {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: translateX(-0.3px) translateY(0.88px) scale(2.0);
}

#mycanvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
Move your mouse over the snippet's iframe to apply the fix
<div class="transformed">
  <div style="background-size:contain;background-image:url('https://zwibbler.com/clipart/image/105446-2000px.png');width:1000px;height:1000px;background-size:contain"></div>

  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```